# Why different background colors for signature image?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-card

May be my question look non-productive and poor but I wish to know if there is any logic behind  that "why different image backgrounds appear?", For example on most of my Q&A my signature image  look like:

> [image: image-2]

But on some pages  like [this "question and answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13648491/1673391), signature image looks *better* like as below:

> [image: image-2]

My question is regarding [stackoverflow web](https://stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: You self-answered.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes I answer my self there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok I didn't read the linked post I will read there also. thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you self-answer, your background colour changes to indicate you are also the author of the question. On questions you ask, the background colour is always offset.

This echos the same background change when you comment, and in suggested edits to mark the owner of the edited post.

Comment: But what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893379/listen-queue-length-in-socket-programing-in-c)

Comment: because I edit accepted answer ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: you mean on the question, or where you edited? That wasn't your answer, so the edit background is still white. It doesn't matter for edits if you are he question OP or not. On your question you are still the owner of that question.

Comment: on my question..